# Disable Spring AOP MethodSecurityInterceptor when using AspectJ CTW

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop, compile-time-weaving

I have a project which uses Spring Security and is making of AspectJ compile time weaving (CTW) to weave in `spring-security-aspects`. This allows me to use annotations such as `@PreAuthorize` in non-Spring managed classes (which works fine) but I'm having problems with the Spring managed classes now.

I have a Controller (annotated with `@Controller`) with this method:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
public String test()
{
    return "test";
}
```

This all seem to work fine except Spring still seems to be proxying the Controller bean and hitting the `MethodSecurityInterceptor`. This means the `hasRole()` method gets hit twice, once from the proxy and a second time from AspectJ woven code.

I am using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and have global method security enabled `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)`. I suspect that something in my configuration is messing things up, does anyone with a bit more knowledge of Spring Security or Spring AOP know what might be going on here?

The controller has definitely been woven with the AspectJ code as it's visible in the (decompiled) class file:

```
    JoinPoint var5 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_2, this, this, test, model);
    AnnotationSecurityAspect var10000 = AnnotationSecurityAspect.aspectOf();
    Object[] var6 = new Object[]{this, search, model, var5};
    return (String)var10000.ajc$around$org_springframework_security_access_intercept_aspectj_aspect_AnnotationSecurityAspect$1$c4d57a2b(new TestController$AjcClosure5(var6), var5);
```

This is a partial stack trace that may help explain what's going on, essentially when the MethodSecurityInterceptor has done it's work and calls `mi.proceed()` it will then hit the AspectJ code weaved in the method body.

```
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
  at com.example.controller.TestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e3715a5.test(<generated>:-1)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-1)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:799)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:728)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:51)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:233)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:213)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
  - locked <0x1e9e> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I seem to have had some success by excluding AOP auto configuration using `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {AopAutoConfiguration.class})` although I'm not sure if there any side effects yet.

Comment: Upgrade to Spring Security 4.0.2. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-3045

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! that seems to have sorted it, I'd have never have found that issue on my own. If you convert your comment to an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with not properly honoring the AspectJ configuration when using the namespace of java based configuration. This has been resolved the current (4.0.2) version of Spring Security.

See [SEC-3045](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-3045) for more information.